# unexpected behavior with EnumMeta class

Tags: python, enums

I defined an `IntEnum` for some weather codes and provided a metaclass.

```py
from enum import IntEnum, EnumMeta

class WXCodeMeta(EnumMeta):
    def __iter__(self: type[IntEnum]) -> Iterator[tuple[str, int]]:
        for member in super().__iter__():
            yield member.name, member.value
            
    def names(self: type[IntEnum]):
        return tuple(member.name for member in super().__iter__())

    def values(self: type[IntEnum]):
        return tuple(member.value for member in super().__iter__())

class WXCodes(IntEnum, metaclass=WXCodeMeta):
    RA = 1
    TS = 2
    BR = 3
    SN = 4
    FG = 5
```

as show above it functions as expected when passed into a `dict`.

```py
>>> dict(WXCodes)
{'RA': 1, 'TS': 2, 'BR': 3, 'SN': 4, 'FG': 5}
```

but if I change the method name of `names` to `keys` like ...

```py
class WXCodeMeta(EnumMeta):
    ...    
    def keys(self: type[IntEnum]):
        return tuple(member.name for member in super().__iter__())
```

I get an unexpected result

```py
>>> dict(WXCodes)
{'RA': <WXCodes.RA: 1>,
 'TS': <WXCodes.TS: 2>,
 'BR': <WXCodes.BR: 3>,
 'SN': <WXCodes.SN: 4>,
 'FG': <WXCodes.FG: 5>}
```

It was my understanding that `dict` calls the `__iter__` method under the hood to create a `__new__` `dict`.  Why does the `keys` method name change the behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using `dict` to construct dictionary objects, it will create an empty dictionary first. If there are arguments, the arguments will be passed to its `update` method. It's not convenient to directly show the C code of `dict.update`, so the [`MutableMapping.update`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/_collections_abc.py#L967) method in `_collections_abc.py` is provided here, from which we can see the update idea of `dict.update`:

```
class MutableMapping(Mapping):
    ...
        def update(self, other=(), /, **kwds):
        '''...'''
        if isinstance(other, Mapping):
            for key in other:
                self[key] = other[key]
        elif hasattr(other, "keys"):
            for key in other.keys():
                self[key] = other[key]
        else:
            for key, value in other:
                self[key] = value
        for key, value in kwds.items():
            self[key] = value
    ...
```

When the `other` passed in is not a mapping, `MutableMapping` will first check whether the `other` has `keys` method. If so, it will try to iterate and get the corresponding value to update, rather than directly iterate over the `other` object. It happens that `EnumMeta.__getitem__` method gets the enumeration object itself according to its name, so you get a dictionary with name as the key and enumeration object as the value.